# How can I create animations as the animations of iMessage in IOS 10?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, swift3, ios10

First, sorry for my bad English !

I want to create animations like the animations in IMessage in IOS 10, so like balloon, confetti and others, like this:
[Imessage animations in IOS 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1RUe.jpg)

I want to add this animations in an UIView, so animations will be animated only in the UIView, I don't know if it's possible and how to do that ( Google didn't give me a response.. )

I tried with SceneKit View with particle animations but it doesn't really work ( particles are fuzzy and it's very strange ), and I don't think Apple use this to create their animations in iMessage..

So how can I create animations like iMessage animations in IOS 10 please ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read this to write better questions and thus get better answers in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask In regards to your question, google for "uiview animate()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that apple just uses videos as their source. Especially on older devices running iOS10 like the iPhone 4S, rendering these in realtime would not be as fluently as they are right now.

Comment: It is true that I did not really think of this method thank you so much !
I went to see on Google, indeed it is possible to create transparent videos to see the contents behind, as Imessage. Thanks a lot !